# Why doesn't fmt.Scanf in Go wait for user input?

Tags: go

I am working through Caleb Doxsey's Go book and I have two questions about `fmt.Scanf` http://www.golang-book.com/4

I am wondering why the program does not stop after the second Scanf and wait for user input? And how do I test if the user entered an integer and/or did not leave blank?

```
package main

import (
"fmt"
//"math"
)


// compute square roots by using Newton's method

func main() {

var x float64           //number to take square root
var y float64           //this is the guess
var q float64           //this is the quotient
var a float64           //this is the average


// how do check if the user entered a number
fmt.Print("Enter a number to take its square root: ")
var inputSquare float64
fmt.Scanf("%f", &inputSquare)

// why doesn't program stop after 
// the Print statement and wait
// for user input?
fmt.Print("Enter first guess ")
var inputGuess float64
fmt.Scanf("%f", &inputGuess)

//x = 2
x = inputSquare
y = inputGuess

for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {   //set up the for loop for iterations
    q = x/y                 //compute the quotient; x and y are given
    a = (q + y) / x         //compute the average       
    y = a                   //set the guess to the average              
}                           //for the next loop


fmt.Println("y --> ", y)
//fmt.Println("Sqrt(2)", math.Sqrt(2))
}
```

Comment: It works properly for me. I'm going to guess that it's a line ending issue. If you're running on Windows, line endings are conventionally denoted by '\r\n', whereas on Mac OS X and Linux (where I tested this), it's just '\n'. My guess is that maybe Go is reading the '\r' , treating it as a line ending, and leaving the '\n' on the stream. So when you call fmt.Scanf again, there's already something in the buffer and no need to block. This is just a wild guess though.

Comment: ok. Any suggestions how to fix it? This is what I get running in Windows command line: c:\Go\src\play\exercise>go run loop_exercise.go
Enter a number to take its square root: 2
Enter first guess y -->  +Inf

Comment: What happens if you explicitly read a newline character with the Scanf call? Like "`fmt.Scanf("%f\n", &inputGuess)`"? Alternately, you could flush stdin after each read. I don't know go well enough to know where to tell you to look for a Flush function.

Comment: Yes, adding `\n` fixed the issue.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

*Update*: was [fixed almost a decade ago](https://github.com/golang/go/commit/221af5c12fe9769b723b8af2f000ed5f39a5dbb3).   [The docs for `fmt`](https://pkg.go.dev/fmt) now read

> In all the scanning functions, a carriage return followed immediately by a newline is treated as a plain newline (\r\n means the same as \n).

If you continue to have scanning errors, [mind that it isn't your IDE's fault](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71244343/1726083).

---

It's [Issue 5391](http://code.google.com/p/go/issues/detail?id=5391): `fmt`: `Scanf` rejects `\r\n` at end of line on Windows.

As a workaround and to check for valid input, write,

```
var inputSquare float64
n, err := fmt.Scanf("%f\n", &inputSquare)
if err != nil || n != 1 {
    // handle invalid input
    fmt.Println(n, err)
}
```

and

```
var inputGuess float64
n, err = fmt.Scanf("%f\n", &inputGuess)
if err != nil || n != 1 {
    // handle invalid input
    fmt.Println(n, err)
}
```

The workaround is the newline in the `"%f\n"` format strings.

> Package `fmt`
>
> [func Scanf](http://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Scanf)
>
> ```
> func Scanf(format string, a ...interface{}) (n int, err error)
> ```
>
> `Scanf` scans text read from standard input, storing successive
> space-separated values into successive arguments as determined by the
> format. It returns the number of items successfully scanned.

Here's a complete working program:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

// compute square roots by using Newton's method
func main() {
    var x float64 //number to take square root
    var y float64 //this is the guess
    var q float64 //this is the quotient
    var a float64 //this is the average

    fmt.Print("Enter a number to take its square root: ")
    var inputSquare float64
    n, err := fmt.Scanf("%f\n", &inputSquare)
    if err != nil || n != 1 {
        // handle invalid input
        fmt.Println(n, err)
        return
    }

    fmt.Print("Enter first guess ")
    var inputGuess float64
    n, err = fmt.Scanf("%f\n", &inputGuess)
    if err != nil || n != 1 {
        // handle invalid input
        fmt.Println(n, err)
        return
    }

    x = inputSquare
    y = inputGuess
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        q = x / y       // compute the quotient; x and y are given
        a = (q + y) / x // compute the average
        y = a           // set the guess to the average
    }
    fmt.Printf("sqrt(%g) = %g\n", x, y)
}
```

Output:

```
Enter a number to take its square root: 2.0
Enter first guess 1.0
sqrt(2) = 1.414213562373095
```

I used Go 1.1.1 on Windows 7:

```
C:\>go version
go version go1.1.1 windows/amd64
```

Comment: Thanks. Does `fmt.Scanf()` return an error? I assume, `n` is the input and `err` is the possible error message in `n, err := fmt.Scanf("%f\n", &inputSquare)`Is this correct?

Comment: See my revised answer. `n` is the number of items successfully scanned and `err` reports any errors encountered during the scan. Therefore, if there was an error or the number of items scanned isn't what you expect (`err != nil || n != 1`), do something to handle the error. However, if all goes well (`err == nil && n == 1`), the valid input, as a floating-point number (`float64`), can be read from  `*inputSquare`. In your code, you discarded `n` and `err`, that's why you didn't notice errors.

Comment: I must be doing something wrong. If I run the program with the error handling part `n, err := fmt.Scanf("f\n", &inputSquare)    // pick up the error 
 if err != nil || n != 1 {
  fmt.Println(n, err)` I get "0 input does not match format" (I enter, for instance, 2.0 for inputSquare) If I comment out the error handling it all works fine! What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I've revised my answer to provide a complete working program. What output do you get when you run the program?