# Flushing stdin buffer in Golang?

Tags: go

I'm new programming with Go.
I've been writing this little program that uses structures.
It's a structure called user, which has as values, first name, last name and age.
The problem lies when entering data, more specifically when it comes to entering the last name, this error happens:
[a screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/puMjq.png)

You can see from the image that when you introduces data in the name field,
ignores last name field, and jumps to age.

Having knowledge in C, this error happens when the buffer has not been flushed. (but C is a different language from Go)

As I know, Go stdin read is unbuffered.
So how would you solve this problem?

Here's the code:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type user struct {
    name, surnm string
    age int
}

func main() {

    n := new(user)

    fmt.Print("Name? ")
    fmt.Scanf("%s", &n.name)

    fmt.Print("Last name? ")
    fmt.Scanf("%s", &n.surnm)

    fmt.Print("Age? ")    
    fmt.Scanf("%d", &n.age)

    fmt.Println(n.name)         
    fmt.Println(n.surnm)
    fmt.Println(n.age)

}
```

Sorry if my question is a little bit stupid, but how I said, I am new at Go.

Comment: Are you on Windows? It works fine for me on OS X but you might have [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17401709/why-doesnt-fmt-scanf-in-go-wait-for-user-input) resolved by using a `\n` at the end of your patterns, i.e. `fmt.Scanf("%s\n", &n.name)`.

Comment: @Matt Yes I'm in Windows, and now works, thanks!

Comment: Great. It seems to be a bug with different line endings (Windows uses `\r\n` to terminate a line, most other OS's just use `\n`). `Scanf` consumes `blah\r` and drops the `\r`, but it does not consume the `\n` so the next call to `Scanf` finds `\n` in the buffer, consumes it and drops it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a little difficult to reproduce on go 1.11 on Ubuntu
I am guessing you are using a Microsoft operating system of some sort
Microsoft have line endings of \r\n, return + newline whereas Unix-like systems have just \n newline only

If I fake up an input file for your program that has \r\n line endings
it does seem to skip

Whereas an input file with only \n makes the program work correctly

Adding explicit \r to the pattern as shown seems to fix the problem

```
fmt.Print("Name? ")
fmt.Scanf("%s\r", &n.name)

fmt.Print("Last name? ")
fmt.Scanf("%s\r", &n.surnm)

fmt.Print("Age? ")
fmt.Scanf("%d\r", &n.age)
```

This is curious as the [go documentation on scanf](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/) states

> In all the scanning functions, a carriage return followed immediately
>   by a newline is treated as a plain newline (\r\n means the same as
>   \n).

To be fair, once the changes above are made the code behaves the same for \n files and \r\n files

Comment: adding \n instead of \r to the input patterns also works, as discussed in the comments

Comment: Yes I'm using Windows... Windows, why you can't be normal?