# why fmt.Scanf("%s", &name) print the previous value

Tags: go

I make this code for learning:-

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
)

func main() {

    for {
        name := ""
        fmt.Print("Enter : ")
        fmt.Scanf("%s", &name)
        b1, _ := strconv.ParseBool(name)
        fmt.Printf("%T, %v\n", b1, b1)
    }

}
```

output:

> Enter : True
>
> bool, true
>
> Enter : bool, false
>
> Enter :

***why there is an extra "Enter: bool, false" line?***
edit:
this will happen in Powershell, cmd and bash in windows but not in wsl.
[image]

Edit: this was the same [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17401709/why-doesnt-fmt-scanf-in-go-wait-for-user-input) but it is a different question. and the solution there as I mentioned is outdated, It was updated after I mentioned it in my answer but I have to confirm and check that.

Comment: Just print `name` to find out what it contains.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt do you mean this is what copiler do? how I can remove it?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. My suggestion was to check what `name` contains in between the call to `fmt.Scanf()` and `strconv.ParseBool()`. Those are two operations and the outcome of them surprises you, so split them and see which one is the cause of it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why doesn't fmt.Scanf in Go wait for user input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17401709/why-doesnt-fmt-scanf-in-go-wait-for-user-input)

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt thanks for the suggestion I did that it give me an empty and then I try to add print between them and I find that what happens is something like the return buffered I search for delete buffer and I found this answer that I mentioned in my answer. so it was a long journey that can not be done without your help.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt yes this answer "that I already mentioned in my answer yesterday" help me to work around the issue but it is not the right answer (outdated as Daniel Farrell mentioned) so I have to investigate further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you're using some IDE.

sometimes they mess up the console output, try to run directly from native terminal instead. Or use vscode.

[image]

Comment: thanks, I get this extra line when I run this code in vscode PowerShell terminal... I try it in my mobile there is no issue ..

Comment: Yes, @MustafaSalman, try for example cmd prompt or bash

Answer (score 0):

Edit: as @Daniel Farrell mentioned this issue [fixed many years ago.](https://github.com/golang/go/commit/221af5c12fe9769b723b8af2f000ed5f39a5dbb3), but I'm getting this issue in Windows-terminal with (Powershell, cmd, and bash) and the same issue with cmder terminal.
this will not happen with wsl and with  MobaXterm terminal, I did not make further checking with other terminals.

I have to mention that there is an old "deprecated" workaround by adding the new line in the "%s\n" format strings. As in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17401709/why-doesnt-fmt-scanf-in-go-wait-for-user-input)

so the code below will work in all terminals:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
)

func main() {

    for {
        var name string
        fmt.Print("Enter : ")
        fmt.Scanf("%s\n", &name)
        b1, _ := strconv.ParseBool(name)
        fmt.Printf("%T, %v \n", b1, b1)
    }

}
```

Comment: Nope, fixed many years ago.  I updated that accepted answer answer.  I suggest you delete this answer as it's drastically out of date - Sombriks' answer is great here

Comment: Oh, so you found the solution yourself and it was already asked and answered here. Let's close this duplicate question then.

Comment: @DanielFarrell I tried Powershell, cmd, and bash in windows 11and ( without IDE) ... I will download other terminals to check if it is falt of windows terminal then I will update the answer to clarify that...

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Yes  Let's close this,  think nothing is to be done further.

Answer (score -1):

i had retype your code and i got the same as Sombriks, you must have pressed enter key by mistake.

here is a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7rWGs.png)

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
)

func main() {
    for {

        name := ""
        fmt.Print("Enter: ")
        fmt.Scanf("%s", &name)
        b, _ := strconv.ParseBool(name)
        fmt.Printf("%T -  %v\n", b, b)
    }
}
```

Comment: That it works for you doesn't mean the person asking the question is mistaken. It might be related to the environment in which the code is running which is different from yours.

Comment: i realised that after i had answered  the question. As he had edited his question with more detailed explantion.

Comment: Note that you can delete a wrong answer, to prevent confusion for future readers.